# Wordpress - Save to server via Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have form on my wordpress site which concerts to PDF using jsPDF and then should be saved to the server when submitted.

I am getting a success message but the PDF does not appear to be saved to the desired folder. I cannot find where the PDF is or if it is even being saved at all

The code

Registering the Ajax command in functions.php:

```
function eazy_scripts() {
wp_register_script('js-pod', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/POD.js', array('jquery'),'1.1', true);
wp_enqueue_script('js-pod');
wp_localize_script( 'js-pod', 'jspod', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'eazy_scripts' );
```

JS

```
$( "#pdfsubmit" ).click(function() {
            alert("Submitted");
            sendToServer();
        });

        function sendToServer() {

            console.log("#pdfsubmit clicked");
            var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');

            pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById("product_sheet"), function() {

                ps_filename = "generated-product-sheet";
                var file = btoa(pdf.output());

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('data', file);

                $.ajax({
                  url: jspod.ajax_url+'?action=so56917978_upload',
                  data: formData,
                  processData: false,
                  contentType: false,
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function(data){
                      alert(data);
                  }
              });
            });
        }
```

PHP which should save the PDF to server:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_so56917978_upload', 'so56917978_upload_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_so56917978_upload', 'so56917978_upload_callback' );
function so56917978_upload_callback() {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
        $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
        file_put_contents( get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/POD/pod.pdf' , $data );
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "No Data Sent";
    }
    echo 'got there';
    die();
}
```

As mentioned I am getting the success message but nothing seems to be saved.

When I check the network tab I see:[image: Network tab]

The letter string looks like a base64 string and seems very long. a lot longer than what is shown in the picture.

I am wondering if maybe the PHP is not adequate for decoding it and then saving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` which returns directory URL,

Use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to get the actual path of stylesheet directory.

Try changing your function to this and checkout the response from your ajax request

```
function so56917978_upload_callback() {
    $res = [
        'saved' => 0,
    ];

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['data'] ) ) {
        $pdf = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/POD/pod.pdf';
        $data = base64_decode($_POST['data']);
        file_put_contents( $pdf, $data );
        $res['pdf'] = $pdf;
        $res['saved'] = 1;
    } else{
        $res['error'] = 'No Data Sent'; 
    }
    wp_send_json( $res );
}
```

Comment: is there anything I can change `$res = [
        'saved' = 0,
    ];` to? I am getting an error:  `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']' in functions.php`

Comment: Should it be `$res = [
        'saved' , 0
    ];` ?

Comment: I changed it to `$res ['saved'] = 0;` and it worked, thanks a lot :-)

Comment: Can I ask one more question... Ideally, Id like to set the file name in the jQuery so that I can use multiple versions of this but save each pdf with the name set in the jQuery. Also, if I save the form on a desktop or on a phone the dimensions of the PDF are different, is there any way to keep them, consistent?

Comment: have edited my answer, initial ```$res``` var should be ```$res = [
        'saved' => 0,
    ];```  if you want to set the name on jquery just append additional data on your request ```formData.append('fileName', 'MyFileName');``` then on your ```$pdf``` var, get the ```fileName``` value ```$pdf = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/POD/'.$_POST['fileName'].'.pdf';```

Comment: for consistency of the PDF, Im sure this depends/relate with jsPDF you're using